# Django error: database password not found?

Tags: python, django

manage.py runserver shows the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

settings.py contains:

```
DATABASES = {  
  'default': {  
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',  
    'NAME': 'myproj', # name of psql db on your running database server  
    'USER': 'myuser',  
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',  
    'HOST': 'localhost',  
    'PORT': '5432',  
}  
}
```

But, diffsettings is showing that no user or password is set:

```
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2','AUTOCOMMIT': True,  
'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': 'myname', 'TEST_MIRROR':     None, 
'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TEST_NAME': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': 
 None, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'HOST': 'localhost', 'USER': '', 'TEST_CHARSET': None,
'PASSWORD': '', 'PORT': ''}}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like your `manage.py` does not found your settings file. Try to set it explicitly with `--settings` parameter

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL you first need to create database with your hands. It looks like:

```
sudo su - postgres
createdb mydb
createuser -P
psql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;
```